# Color change, primary hover

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm a beginner and a great desire to learn. But despite my best efforts there are things that I cannot solve.

Through the element inspector I understood that this color is the primary hover, set by default with this code: `#eeac00`

I want to change this color with a different code, that is: `#000000`

How can I do it elementor also provides me with a CSS editing section.
In case there was a need.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcWYr.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKU48.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

`.add_to_cart_button:hover{background-color:#000000!important;}`

Comment: Hi, thanks it worked.
But I only changed the background color of the add to cart button.

I wanted to set this color just like the primary hover color.
In order to completely remove this yellow color from the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change this color for all your website you can do it in multiple ways :

- Make a child theme of your Wordpress theme. Then change the color as you want. (Editor -> Appareance)

```
:root{
  --primary_hover: #000000;
}
```

- You can try to add this code into your *Custom CSS* from Elementor. Maybe, will it work.
- Maybe not the best way if you do update of your theme but if not you can directly change it in your theme settings.

Comment: you are a genius thank you, that was exactly what I was trying to do.  It worked.  Thank you very much, now that I have discovered this new 'root' function I am going to inform myself more about it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as solved :)